# Any way to compare many ways in data structure in C++

Tags: c++

For example I have struct

```
struct A {
std::string Id;
std::string Name;
Std::string Year;
};

I defined data type look like
std::map<A, int> MyMap;
```

I put some item to MyMap. I want to find an item that satisfy one of below

```
- MyMap.find(it1); //that return iter if match Id
- MyMap.find(it2); //that return iter if match both Id and Name
- MyMap.find(it3); //that return iter if match all Id, Name,Year
```

I know I must define operator< in struct A but how to define that work with 3 cases above. Or Which data type instead of Map is suitable in this case.

Comment: Probably, you need `std::find_if`.

Comment: @Kane: Tks. I will check it.

Comment: Sounds like a wrong choice of container. A map cannot have multiple definitions of equivalence on its key type.

Comment: you can use `std::find` and pass a predicate

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` can only have one predicate for associating key with a value.

You can use different predicates with the standard algorithm `std::find_if` to achieve this, but it does a linear search, rather than an efficient map lookup.

If you need multiple predicates to look up an element efficiently, then you need a multi-index container. The standard library does not have such a thing, but you can implement one by using multiple maps internally, or you can use a generic solution from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your research is still in same order, you might use something like:

```
struct A {
    std::string Id;
    std::string Name;
    Std::string Year;
};

bool operator < (const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.Id, lhs.Name, lhs.Year) < std::tie(rhs.Id, rhs.Name, rhs.Year);
}


auto findById(const std::map<A, int>&m, const std::string& id)
{
    auto it = m.lower_bound(A{id, "", ""});

    if (it != m.end() && it->first.Id == id) {
        return it;
    }
    return m.end();
}

auto findByIdName(const std::map<A, int>&m, const std::string& id, const std::string& name)
{
    auto it = m.lower_bound(A{id, name, ""});

    if (it != m.end() && it->first.Id == id && it->first.Name == name) {
        return it;
    }
    return m.end();

}

auto findByIdNameYear(const std::map<A, int>&m,
                      const std::string& id,
                      const std::string& name,
                      const std::string& year)
{
    return m.find(A{id, name, year});
}
```

If you prefer to use `std::vector`, you may use `std::find_if` like that:

```
std::vector<A> as = /*...*/;
auto it = std::find_if(as.begin(), as.end(),
                       [&](const A& a){ return a.Id = id && a.Name = name;} );
if (it == as.end()) {
    // Not found
} else {
    // use *it as matching A.
}
```

Comment: Many tks for all. I will check and confirm soon.

Comment: Sorry I intend using vector instead of map.  @Jarod42 could I use your way?
std::vector<A> MyVector;